# Как открыть доступ из сети к Oracle на Win Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, oracle, администрирование

Имеется Windows Server 2008 R2.
На нем установлена БД Oracle.
Запись для tnsname.ora просто скопировал, заменив loaclhost на нужный IP адрес.
Ping между машинами проходит.
tnsping на самой машине работает.
tnsping с другой машины не проходит, возникает ошибка:

> TNS-12541: TNS: no listener

Я пробовал открыть порты на сервере. В брандмауэре создал правило для порта 1521 для всех программ(в Inbound Rules). Добавил oracle.exe и tnslsnr.exe в исключения брандмауэра.

Смотрел через resmon.exe . TNSLSNR.EXE слушает 1521 порт. Firewall Status - Allowed, not Restricted

Подскажите, куда еще надо посмотреть и что подкрутить?

Comment: А 1521 он слушает на всех ip ? может быть он только на 127.0.0.1 слушает ?

Comment: Как и куда посмотреть?

Comment: В файле listener.ora посмотреть какой host у той записи что для TCP/1521. Или то же через lsnrctl команда status

Comment: @Mike да, проблема была в этом. Оформите ответом, приму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо проверить настройки самого слушателя Oralce. Настройки хранятся в файле `%DBHOME%/network/admin/listener.ora`. В записи `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HostName)(PORT = 1521))` в качестве HostName должно быть имя сервера разрешимое по DNS во внешний IP сервера или сам IP. Скорее всего в данный момент там стоит localhost, в итоге Oracle принимает соединения только на локальной машине.